# android accelometer detect jumping?

Tags: java, android

Hi!

I'm just starting out with Android development and i was wondering if there is any built in machinery in Android phones that are able to detect if a person is squatting (if a person holds his phone in his hand and keeps his hand steady, the phone changes it's altitude by approximately 1 m)  or jumping. The user is holding his phone in his hand in both cases. If there is, what kind of packages should one look into to use those built in detectors?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: There isn't anything built in, but what you tried rather than asking for pre-existing packages?

Comment: I've not tried anything yet, at the moment i barely can write a hello world on my phone's screen. I just had an app idea and thought if it was possible to accomplish such a task, so i'd have a motivation to work towards something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases you'll want to make use of the inbuilt accelerometer. Squatting will be very difficult to detect reliably though. Jumping could be quite easy. For example, when jumping, there will be an upward acceleration significantly greater than gravity, followed by free-fall, followed by another upward acceleration upwards. (Landing).

Comment: Thank you. But with the jumping though, would the user be able to "cheat" the device, like moving his/her hand up and down fast, without actually jumping?

Comment: There is simply no way around that.